# Why does Elon Musk say we almost certainly live in a simulated reality?

Tags: simulated-universe

When Morpheus from the Matrix tells us about why the machines use human body heat together with some sort of fusion in order to derive energy, why didn't the machines simply use nuclear, fusion, electromagnetic, geothermal or any given other energy type from our current civilization level (if they are indeed so advanced why not use the energy of the spin of the stars or better yet create one in a vacuum)?

The only explanation is if base reality had a completely different set of physics than the simulated one, the simulated reality would include manufactured "lies" or differences than base reality, what would the simulators possibly gain from creating 30-40 such differences in the simulated reality? Wouldn't simulating a reality according to the physics of the base reality be easier?

It seems that all the evidence seems to point to the contrary and that we almost certainly are in base reality.

Comment: Would you have a reference to Musk's view that we live in a simulated reality? Also the title of the question talks about Musk, but the body talks about the Matrix. I am not sure what the question is. Regardless, welcome!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Musk is probably repeating the conclusion of [Bostrom's simulation argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis#Simulation_hypothesis). But speculating what fictional machines should do to make a fictional simulation, or what hypothetical simulators with unknowable interests operating under unknowable laws might gain from their simulating is not really within the scope of this site.

Comment: @FrankHubeny https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0KHiiTtt4w here is a short video

Comment: @Conifold I could still deduce by attempting to reason as a simulator and question the motives of the simulators among other things.

Comment: Perhaps, but that would be what is called primarily opinion-based, and it is off-topic here. [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) might be a more suitable site.

Comment: I'd rather have Musk doing that than blowing hundreds of millions in tax subsidies, which is his day job. For a hundred years after Newton everyone thought the world was a machine. This week, everyone thinks the world is a computer. It will pass. But at least Musk speculates on his own dime, which is more than I can say for his companies.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why a simulation would contain different physical parameters ("lies"): We do not have perfect knowledge of our reality and there is no reason to assume that any base reality would have; naturally we should expect any simulation to contain approximations. Then again some "lies" may be central to the purpose of the simulation. And of course the simulators may have been programmed to make such mistakes. - Note, I don't think there is any _evidence_ to speak of concerning this, but it is quite prudent to assume we're in a base reality.